# Error: Cant access the filesystem. You can use the getBase64 method [ElectronJS + VueJS]

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am trying to resize my images using JIMP. But I am constantly getting an error saying:

> Error: Cant access the filesystem. You can use the getBase64 method.

I am using:

- ElectronJS
- VueJS
- [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder)

I have also made my Gitlab repository publicly available just in case someone whats to reproduce an error: [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/Kristof89/s3-image-uploader)

I have also found that someone already raised an issue as a bug: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/639

Did anyone had this type of issue?

Comment: In addition to my answer, where are you trying to save the image? On the client machine or on the server?

Comment: Modified answer to show indirect way to save. I resized and saved and it works.

Comment: Any update on this? Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Do not use jimp in your renderer use it in your main. You can trigger jimp inside the main with events (ipcRenderer, ipcMain).
Please read the electron docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

- https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer
- https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Haven't test it, but it should work.

You have to set your **main.js** inside in your **vue.config.js**
https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#webpack-configuration

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      mainProcessFile: 'src/main/main.js'
    }
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const jimp = require('jimp');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });

  win.loadFile('index.html');

  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  // get triggered by renderer
  ipcMain.on('trigger-jimp', (event, arg) => {
    jimp.read(filepaths[0]).then(image => {
      // sends back the image to renderer
      event.sender.send('triggered-jimp', image);
    });
  });

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**OpenDialog.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
  <button v-on:click="openDialog('openDirectory')">Upload Folder</button>
  <button v-on:click="openDialog('openFile')">Upload File</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

export default {
  methods: {
      dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: [property],
        filters: [{name: 'Images', extensions: ['png', 'jpg',  'gif']}]
      })
      }, function(filepaths) {
        console.log(filepaths);
        // send path to yout main
        ipcRenderer.send('trigger-jimp', filepaths);
      });
    },
    handleImage(image) {
      console.log(image);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // get image from main
    ipcRenderer.on('jimp-triggered', this.handleImage);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // remove the listener
    ipcMain.removeListener('jimp-triggered', this.handleImage);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to fix the error for writing but I can show you how to get around it by using the base64 data. I actually downloaded your code and tested it.

### Changes to html

```
  <button v-on:click="openDialog('openFile')">Upload File</button>
  <img id="image" src=""/>
```

### Changes to script

```
jimp.read(filepaths[0], function (err, image) {
  image.resize(200,200);
  image.getBase64(Jimp.AUTO, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", data);
  });
});
```

**Edit** : This is how to write it directly instead of calling jimp.write. You can do your image manipulation (like resize) just before you call image.getBase64.

```
    var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    fs.writeFile("test.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
```